# Azure pipelines. Repeat tasks without project rebuilding

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use azure pipeline for build my solution.

Aftere build I need to generate and upload multiple packages with different assets. Packing implemented as a number of additional tasks in my agent job.

But I need ability to generate only selected packages or all packages based on specified arguments.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Ideally, it would have 2 pipelines. The first is automatic project build. And the second should use the result of the first and be able to repeatedly start manually with the desired parameters to exclude project rebuild. But I do not know how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but two possible answers would be:

Classic pipelines, with build pipeline for project build and release pipeline for uploading the artifact(s) that build generates, if using release pipeline is applicable. Release pipeline can have a cd-trigger for the first run, and redeployed manually after that. If need to change release variables for subsequent deployments, you can create a new release with the same build artifact.
Multi-staged pipeline, with build and upload as different stages, manually redeploy/rerun the upload stage when needed. Build phase generates deployable pipeline artifact(s).

Somehow I think you're looking for more elaborate solution, as you state that you're already using pipelines. So how about creative use of conditional tasks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) using pre-defined variables like Build.Reason (with value 'Manual') to exclude the execution of certain tasks in some runs. Then group tasks you want to re-use into either build templates or task groups.

Comment: For the usage of different artifact types, there's a recent good answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58869538/11034408